# jquery .html() returning null in ie7

Tags: jquery-selectors

On click li element i am getting the current element value and appending it into  another div dynamically.Its working fine in all browsers.But returning null in IE7.I don`t the reason that why its happening?Please can any one give me a solution for this..Part of the code only i pasted here.

**Sample code:**
    ////////////.//This line returning null in IE7./////////////////

```
 $('#pagelink_a #pagelinkli_'+tab_lastid_val).html()

  (tab_lastid_val value can be a 1 or 2 or 3.Clixked li element value comes here)



    <div class="pagelink">
          <div id="pagelink_a">
       <ul>
           /******** all li element are clickable***********/
           <li id="pagelinkli_1"><a>Google</a></li>
           <li id="pagelinkli_2"><a>Chrome</a></li>
           <li id="pagelinkli_3"><a>Firefox</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div?
```

Comment: why dont you just write `$('#pagelinkli_'+tab_lastid_val+'>a').html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $('#pagelink_a').find('li[id=pagelinkli_'+tab_lastid_val']').html();
```

code is not tested but i think it should work.

Comment: i am not using div inside the "pagelink_a" div.Only i am using li element

Comment: Hi the code you given is returning null value in firefox also.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer..now its working fine..sorry i did small mistake in my code

Answer (score 0):

Given your html layout, your parent div is `.pagelink` not `#pagelink_a` , so replace your following line:

```
$('#pagelink_a #pagelinkli_'+tab_lastid_val).html()
```

for this one:

```
$('.pagelink #pagelinkli_'+tab_lastid_val).html()
```

Comment: sorry i missed "pagelink_a" div.now i have added that one.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$('#pagelinkli_'+tab_lastid_val).html()
```

The `#` tag identifies an ID which only a single element may have. There is no need to have anything preceding it. You also labeled the previous class as id, which is wrong. I don't know how your other browsers managed to get anything.

Although bit off topic, it may be better to actually drop IE7 support entirely. Due to small user base and decreasing popularity, it may be costing you more money by support it than to not support it.

Answer (score -2):

Try instead of html() , and try append().
For example

```
$('#ID').append('Your content');
```

Comment: He's not trying to append anything. He's trying to get a return value of it.